# How can I loop through my data, to create a pie chart for each group?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, pie-chart

I am trying to create a loop that'll create a pie chart for the percent recovered vs how many have died in relation to the amount of confirmed cases. The Data below is what my data looks like. I want to use matplotlib to create the pie charts.

```
 death_recovery = df.groupby(['Country'])[['Recovered','Deaths','Confirmed']].sum().reset_index()
 death_recovery
```

[image]

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.pie.html

Comment: What did you try?